# Dissolving Malt Extract for priming

Tags: priming, priming-sugar, lactose

I have a stout I'm going to be bottling soon and unlike past recipes I've brewed which have called for corn sugar for priming, this calls for dry malt extract and lactose.  Typically I've dissolved my corn sugar in a small amount of sterilized (boiled) water to easily introduce it and I'm wondering if there's anything special I should do in this case?

Comment: Isn't the point of boiling to sanitize the sugars you're introducing?  Hopefully the water you're using is already pretty clean.

Comment: I've never had any issues, but I certainly do not consider tap water to be sterile; "clean", perhaps.

Comment: Most tap water is sanitized, especially city water. A lot of us even top up our fermentor with tap water, but my point is that the main reason for boiling in the priming stage is to sanitize the sugar you're adding in. Priming sugar isn't always nice and vacuum packed. It sits around in warehouses and on trucks with who knows what coming into contact with it. I'm simply recommending that you add the sugar in before you boil the water, not after

Comment: Safe for drinking is not the same as sanitized.   I don't think any city water is sanitized in the sense that we typically mean in brewing.

Comment: FWIW, I don't consider the sugar clean either, I was just emphasizing that I boil the tap water when integrating the sugar.  Everything I've read in my (admittedly limited) brewing experiences has strongly advocated against using any unboiled tap water for brewing.

Comment: @theraccoonbrew- I agree that water should usually be boiled as well, I just wanted to emphasize that the sugar should be boiled with it, rather than added in after the boil.

Comment: @baka- All public water systems in the US do provide sanitized drinking water, it's highly regulated by the EPA (http://water.epa.gov/drink/contaminants/index.cfm).  There could be bacteria growing on your faucet, but that can be taken care of with a bowl of sanitizing solution.  I do however still recommend boiling or carbon filtering tap water to get rid of chlorine, but it is, in almost all cases, sanitary.  Well water, on the other hand, is an entirely different story.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you follow the same procedures for the malt extract and lactose that you do for the priming sugar you will be good.  The boiled water acts as a pasteurizer for the sugar and malt extract to eliminate any bacteria.

Answer (score 2):

I would advise against using extract for priming.  There is no advantage to doing so.  In fact, it's more hassle.  You have no idea of the fermentability of the DME, so you have no idea what level of carbonation you'll achieve.  Sugar is fast, reliable, and tasteless.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why might a recipe call for the DME + lactose?  I'm assuming it's contributing some character to the final beer and not merely serving as primer, or am I wrong in that assumption?

Comment: My thought was that since the DME wouldn't get fully converted, it would leave some sweetness behind. And the lactose would give you a milky flavor. So the recipe is probably aiming for a sweet, milk stout.

Comment: Indeed it is :)  I think I'll use the DME + Lactose per the recipe to see what the results are.